django login doesnt redirects without refresh the page
Im a frontend developer and Im working on a login page with a backend team that uses Django. in my login.html file there is a form that gets phone number and password from user. Im getting the user inputs from the from through javascript and after validation send it to backend through a fetch request. but there is a problem. the backend guy said that:"I get the phone number and password correctly through your request and redirects the page to the new url if password and phone number was true and Django redirects correctly but the browser doesnt go to the new page and I should refresh the browser. when I refresh the browser it goes to the new page correctly".
I searched in stackoverflow and checked similar Django redirect issues but none of them was my problem. I also asked Gemini but it didnt give me any good response.
I provide both Django redirect code and my Javascript and html code:


// ================================================ from validation:

      const form = document.querySelector("form");

      const phoneRegEx = /^09\d{9}$/;

      const formData = new FormData();

      form.addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const phone_value = document.querySelector(".phone").value;
        const passwordValue =                      document.querySelector(".password").value;
        document.querySelector(".phone").classList.remove("notValid");
        document.querySelector(".password").classList.remove("notValid");
        document.querySelector(".password-empty-error").style.display = "none";
        document.querySelector(".phone-empty-error").style.display = "none";
        document.querySelector(".phone-invalid-error").style.display = "none";
        if (phone_value && passwordValue) {
          if (phoneRegEx.test(phone_value)) {
            formData.append("phoneNumber", phone_value);
            formData.append("password", passwordValue);
            // for (const key of formData.keys()) {
            //     console.log(key, ":", formData.get(key));
            // }

            function getCookie(name) {
              let cookieValue = null;
              if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== "") {
                const cookies = document.cookie.split(";");
                for (let i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                  const cookie = cookies[i].trim();
                  // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                  if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === name + "=") {
                    cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(
                      cookie.substring(name.length + 1)
                    );
                    break;
                  }
                }
              }
              return cookieValue;
            }
            const csrftoken = getCookie("csrftoken");
            fetch(window.location.href, {
              method: "POST",
              body: formData,
              headers: { "X-CSRFToken": csrftoken ? csrftoken : "" },
            })
              .then((response) => {
                return response.json();
              })
              .then((data) => {
                if (data.message === false) {
                  swal.fire({
                    icon: "error",
                    text: "رمز عبور اشتباه است!",
                  });
                }
              })
              .catch((err) => {});
<form action="/" method="post">
       {% csrf_token %}
       <div class="form-group">
                <input
                  placeholder="شماره موبایل"
                  class="form-control text-right phone"
                  type="text"
                  name="phone"
                />

                <small class="phone-empty-error text-danger">
                  لطفا این قسمت را خالی نگذارید
                </small>
                <small class="phone-invalid-error text-danger">
                  شماره موبایل نادرست است
                </small>
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
                <input
                  placeholder="رمز عبور"
                  class="form-control text-right password"
                  type="password"
                  name="password"
                />

                <small class="password-empty-error text-danger">
                  لطفا این قسمت را خالی نگذارید
                </small>
        </div>
         <div class="container remember d-flex justify-content-                    between mt-3">
                <span>
                  <a class="text-dark" href="{% url 'forgot'      %}">فراموشی رمز</a>
                </span>
          </div>

              <button class="btn login-btn w-100 mt-3 mb-2"                          type="submit">
                 ورود
              </button>
             
</form>



def Login(request):

if request.method == 'POST':
    phone_number = request.POST.get('phoneNumber')
    password = request.POST.get("password")
    user = authenticate(request, username=phone_number, password=password)
    if user is not None and user.is_active:
        login(request, user)

        return redirect(reverse('eadmin'))
    return JsonResponse({'message' : False})
else:
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(reverse('eadmin'))

    return render(request, '../templates/login/login.html')


I'm not sure I'm following correctly. If you are asking how to do a redirect in JS, that is pretty standard. You cannot implement a redirect in a Django view if it is being called via AJAX, you have to redirect in the JS...that aside, it appears your view for the login is not created correctly, you have JSONResponses mixed with redirects which don't make sense: return redirect(reverse('eadmin'))     return JsonResponse({'message' : False})

salam dash sepehr ..... look, the problem was raised from your template. In your login.html you should change the name attribute of the phone tag as equal to your views.py . I mean you typed phone in template and in login view you in request.POST['phone'] typed phoneNumber . That's the real problem. Make them equal and you are good to go.
One more thing : you need to remove this line too (I think):
return JsonResponse({'message' : False})

from your view. Make the changes and send comment here.
Try this one

unfortunately your approach didnt work. beside, the line 'return JsonResponse({'message' : False})'  is because when the password is wrong I get this as a message and show an error mesage to the user from UI.
